# what is "if (predicate(item, index))" operation in LINQ?

Tags: c#, linq

I am fairly new to LINQ. I am looking at this code, and not sure if I understand this properly. I realize that it is an extension and generic method, but what is `predicate(item, index)` performing (lets say i pass in an array of ints when calling this method)?

I know that predicate is a delegate, but maybe I just don't know how delegation works, someone has any good example/explanation they'd like to give. Also, what is `yield` keyword, is it just used in linq stuff?

```
private static IEnumerable<TSource> WhereImpl<TSource>(
    this IEnumerable<TSource> source,
    Func<TSource, int, bool> predicate)
{
    int index = 0;
    foreach (TSource item in source)
    {
        if (predicate(item, index))
        {
            yield return item;
        }
        index++;
    }
}
```

I am trying to follow [Reimplementing LINQ to Objects: Part 2 - "Where"](http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2010/09/03/reimplementing-linq-to-objects-part-2-quot-where-quot.aspx) from Skeet's blog.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
predicate(item, index)
```

is defined to be of type

```
Func<TSource, int, bool>
```

that means a method that has parameters of `TSource` and `int` and returns a `bool` - a predicate.

An example for `TSource` = `string` could be (totally made up):

```
bool IsLengthLargerThan(string s, int length)
{
  return s.Length > length;
}
```

> Also, what is yield keyword, is it
>   just used in linq stuff?

[`yield`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9k7k7cf0.aspx) is specific to iterator blocks - this has been around before LINQ. It basically works like a state machine - `yield return item;` will return item to the caller and suspend execution, but once you request the next item, execution will resume on the next line. It's easiest to see how it works if you step through it with a debugger.

Comment: thanks, but I still don't get the `if (predicate(item, index))` line in the context of my question? When would `(predicate(item, index)` be `true`?

Comment: @Voodoo: This is the whole point of `WhereImpl` - it filters out all items in the collection where the condition defined by the predicate is not true. When that condition is true totally depends on the delegate that you pass in, i.e. if you pass in a delegate that always returns false, you will get back an empty collection. Don't get confused by the index parameter, this is just an additional criteria for the predicate, i.e. you could filter out every odd item by looking at the index.

Comment: stepping through with the debugger also help me answer this question, i.e. `predicate(item, index)` is executing the delegate method `x < 4 && index > 0` in `source.Where((x, index) => x < 4 && index > 0);`

Answer (score 0):

First the `predicate(item, index)` is a delegate that takes in the item in the enumeration and the index of that item in the enumeration.  So if you started with an array of integers, the item would be an integer and the index would be its index in the array.  This index is the result of the current instance of the enumeration so if you add a Where clause and the original index of an item was 3 and the where filtered out the first 3 then its new index would be 0.

The [yield](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9k7k7cf0%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) keyword is a C# keyword for easy output of an IEnumerable.

Answer (score 0):

`predicate(..)` is a function that takes 2 parameters, a string and an int, and return true or false. `yield return` is a keyword that essentially is like saying "yea, add this to the IEnumerable that I'll be returning, but let's keep looking for others"

So it executes the `predicate` function with a string and an int. You see index was initialized to 0 and is auto-incremented every time. That's the second param to predicate. When the function returns true, you say "add it to my return collection"